# (Button)sender).Tag) Выводит 0

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите разобраться, вместо того, почему i присваивается 0?
Да и как вообще работает Tag.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)(sender)).Tag);
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            excelapp = new Excel.Application();
            excelapp.Visible = true;
            excelapp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3;
            excelapp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            excelapp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 5;
            excelapp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            break;
        case 2:
            excelapp.Quit();
            break;
        default:
            Close();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tag это простое свойство, которое по умолчанию [равно Null](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.7.2). Оно по сути аналогично имени, или не знаю, текста кнопки, раз задали определенный текст и забыли. Вы его хоть задаете где то или ждете, что там мистическим образом должно что то появиться?

Comment: В свойствах контрола, сперва задайте значение этого свойства, а потом ловите. По умолчанию тип Tag == object, тоесть понадобиться приведение к типу, что то в этом духе: `string aaa = (string)control.Tag;`

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.